# Rotating tiles; how to delay a transition after hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm brand spankin' new to Javascript. Here's what I want to do. I want an array of square tiles covering the window and I want them to flip over when the mouse goes over them. I already have a single tile. See the Jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/V7cS8/

I would like it so that the tile will flip over completely to the back side, even if the user doesn't hover for the entire animation length (basically, even if the hover is only very brief, I want it to commit to rotating). I want it to hold its flipped state for some minimum amount time and then return if the user is no longer hovering.

Should I be trying to do this entirely in javascript or still using a lot of CSS?

Comment: brmmm, brmmm, I thought this said rotating ***tires*** at first !

Comment: For the rotation, you don't need JavaScript/jQuery at all. Replace all `.flip` references in your CSS by `:hover`: http://jsfiddle.net/V7cS8/1/.

Comment: Oh, wow. That cleans up the code a lot. Is there an easy way to accomplish the delays using this method? I tried transition-delay and it looks pretty messy. http://jsfiddle.net/s9xcP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript/jQuery at all. Replace all `.flip` references in your CSS by `:hover`: http://jsfiddle.net/V7cS8/1/

For delays, you can use [`transition-delay: 1s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition-delay/).

Apply `transition-delay:1s;` (delay 1 second, with vendor prefixes) to the normal selector, and `transition-delay:0s` to the `:hover` selector. The result is that the backflip will be delayed for 1 second.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s9xcP/2/

**Outcome of comment chain:** When existing animations have to be completed first, regardless of the hover state, a JavaScript timeout have to be used:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nY8U8/224/

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        
        // If not not-ready, do nothing
        // By default, the value is `undefined`, !undefined === true
        var not_ready = $this.data('box-hover-not-ready');
        if (!not_ready) {
            $this.addClass('hover');
        } else {
            // If bosy, defer hover transition
            $this.data('box-hover-hovered', true);
        }
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('hover');

        // Mark state as "busy"
        $this.data('box-hover-not-ready', true);
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            var hovered = $this.data('box-hover-hovered');
            if (hovered) {
                // If a hover transition is deferred, activate it now.
                $this.addClass('hover');
                $this.data('box-hover-hovered', false);
            }
            // Mark state as "not busy"
            $this.data('box-hover-not-ready', false);
        }, 2000); /* 2 seconds*/
        
        // Remove previous timeout, set new one.
        clearTimeout($this.data('box-hover-timeout'));
        $this.data('box-hover-timeout', timeout);
    });
});
```

Comment: I was having trouble getting it to be symmetrical, I finally got what I was after. http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/nY8U8/  Do you know how to make it so that a mouseover commits to the flip? When the transitions are long and the user drags the mouse on and back off quickly, the animation reverses without completing.

Comment: @Chet You can use `transition: background 5s 2s;` ([a shorthand for:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition/) animate background, duration 5 secs, delay 2secs, vendor prefixes). See http://jsfiddle.net/nY8U8/222/

Comment: That will probably serve my purpose, but it seems that it doesn't force the animation to completion, it just gives the user a chance to complete the action by returning the hover state. Does css provide a convenient way to force the completion of the animation?

Comment: @Chet You can use JavaScript to add and remove a specific class which immediately resets the delay. A pure CSS method is to add a `:hover` pseudo-selector to the parent. Using this method, transitions can be ended, but following very strict rules: http://jsfiddle.net/nY8U8/223/

Comment: I appreciate your help and I am certainly learning a lot from this, but I think I may be miscommunicating what I am trying to do. Say for example, the user moves off the side of the box and the slow transition starts. Before the slow transition is over (before the box turns white), the user returns to the box. Can I insure that the box will continue to fade to white even if the user does an action that would normally cause it to turn yellow. I want to make the fade out to white impossible to interrupt.

Comment: @Chet No, CSS transitions are, well, *transitions*. On hover, a new set of properties are defined, which are applied via  a smooth transition. On mouseleave, the `:hover` styles aren't applied any more, and the default styles are applied again. With a transition. You have to use jQuery's `hover`, see this **full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nY8U8/224/**